# Steam API Screen Shot Grabbing PHP

Tags: php, api, steam

I am working on a image hosting site powered by steam everything is going pretty smooth. But one feature I would really like is getting users Screen Shot Showcase from their steam profile if they have a Screen Shot Showcase. I am still pretty new to php and api but I know my way around I just do not know the right setups. This is the code I am basing it off from.

```
function grabScreenData() {
global $DB;
if($this->isLoggedin()) {
// Grab the info from the session
$userData = $DB->getUserById($_SESSION['steam']);
if(isset($userData['steamid'])) {
$this->user = $userData;
} else {
unset($_SESSION['steam']);
die('Could not get user');
}
} elseif(isset($_SESSION['loginid'])) {
$url = 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamRemoteStorage/GetUGCFileDetails/v1/?key='.$this->api.'&steamids='.$_SESSION['loginid']'&appid=440''&ugcid=280174773';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$content = json_decode($content, true);
$_SESSION['steam'] = $_SESSION['loginid'];
// Set the database values
$values = array(
'steamid' => $content['data']['status'][0]['steamid'],
'filename' => $content['data']['status'][0]['filename'],
'url' => $content['data']['status'][0]['url'],
'size' => $content['data']['status'][0]['size'],
);
// Are updating the user info or adding them?
$userExists = $DB->getUserById($uid);
if(isset($userExists['steamid'])) {
// We have this user, lets update their info
$DB->update('screenshots', $values, array('steamid' => $_SESSION['steam']));
} else {
// New user, lets insert them
$id = $DB->insert('screenshots', $values);
}
unset($_SESSION['loginid']);
$this->grabScreenData();
}
}
```

What this function is suppose to do is grab this data [GetUGCFileDetails](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/WebAPI/GetUGCFileDetails)

More then likely I setup the api call wrong if anyone would be kind enough to help me out I would really appreciate it because it is driving me nuts lol. I use the same call function to grab user data and it works just changed stuff around. Maybe someone on here is knowledgeable about php,curl and api data grabbing :).